# Does a different behaviour need different visual design?

Tags: tables, drilldown

in a form i'm making, a user needs to select a certain service level agreement. To select the right one the user can first define a couple of parameters like company, customer, contactperson,...

For the same kind of inputfield i have 2 different behaviours:

1. To select an customer, the user is directed to a drilldown page with all the info
2. To select a contactperson the user can directly select one from a foldout lookuptable (don't know the exact name here) that shows up under the inputfield. So no need to go to another page.

**Can i use the same visual information for the two?** I mean, for customer, can i place the magnifier within the inputfiled like i do with contacperson? Because as a user i would expect the same behaviour with the search options within the 2 inputfields, except they're different.
I have designed them differently now.

Note: I'm using a drilldown with the first because this table will generally hold a lot of data and for perfomance issues, i don't want it to load into the page. Default behaviour however is a foldout lookup table for tables that hold little information.

I hop this is somewhat clear?

Thank your for some input.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How are the two related? I am asking this since a contact person, I assume will always be related to the customer. In which case, once the customer is selected, can you just show the list of available contact which would be a a relatively shorter drop down?

I am getting to the point of you making sure that all the fields within your form are needed, seems like most of which can be pre-filled as soon as the user choses the customer.

TO answer your initial question, if possible I think similar visual items should try to behave like each other, both visually and functionally. For the sake of consistency. Do however keep in mind, as you mentioned that you don't want to compromise the UX by having longer load times or lag between the action. Assuming this is a system that will be used often in a working environment, you need to have this working as smoothly as possible.

Comment: they are related, so when a user has selected a customer he can select his contactperson easily because the list will be narrowed down. But there can still be a lot of contactpersons, eg when it is a very large company